# What are the characteristics of a 'Hybrid Model' in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, regression, ensemble-learning

For example, lets say that i'm working with optimization, ensemble learning, and some basic regressors. If i use the ensemble learning, it will not be an hybrid model, but if i combine it with the optimization algorithm can it be considered an hybrid model since i'm using two types of techniques to improve the final result? Or it will just be an "optimized model"? I'm also looking for some solid definition about what a hybrid model is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: @desertnaut Yes, it might be better placed in the AI Stackexchange.

Comment: @OliverMason exactly. You may want to have a look at [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) and [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?” FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hybrid model is one that combines different approaches. Typically, most approaches to solve AI problems have their own advantages and disadvantages, and by combining different ones you can compensate for the weaknesses of one if the other is stronger in those areas.

For example stochastic parts-of-speech tagging: this works generally well, but because language is not very regular, there are some cases where a machine learning/stochastic model will get consistently the wrong answers. However, if you add another approach at the post-processing stage, such as rule-based tagging, you can design rules that identify the systematic errors of the stochastic model and correct them. Your overall accuracy has now improved beyond what a stochastic model or a rule-based approach can achieve on their own.